# SQL SERVER error handler , try catch in insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, triggers, try-catch

I have an Errorlog table , a stored proc to insert error details into the table and an insert trigger . However when I call the stored proc within the insert trigger errors are not being captured . Instead , it is giving me this error below,

```
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
```

Here is my error log table ,

```
CREATE TABLE ErrorLog
 (
     [Error_Number] INT NOT NULL,
     [Error_LINE] INT NOT NULL,
     [Error_Location] sysname NOT NULL,
     [Error_Message] VARCHAR(MAX),
     [SPID] INT, 
    [Program_Name] VARCHAR(255),
     [Client_Address] VARCHAR(255),
     [Authentication] VARCHAR(50),
     [Error_User_Application] VARCHAR(100),
     [Error_Date] datetime NULL
         CONSTRAINT dfltErrorLog_error_date DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
     [Error_User_System] sysname NOT NULL
         CONSTRAINT dfltErrorLog_error_user_system DEFAULT (SUSER_SNAME())
 )
 GO
```

Stored proc ,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ErrorLog_proc]
 (
     @Error_Number INT = NULL,
     @Error_LINE INT = NULL,
     @Error_Location sysname = NULL,
     @Error_Message VARCHAR(4000) = NULL,
     @UserID INT = NULL
 ) 
AS
 BEGIN
     BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO ErrorLog
         (
             [Error_Number]
             ,[Error_LINE]
             ,[Error_Location]
             ,[Error_Message]
             ,[SPID]
             ,[Program_Name]
             ,[Client_Address]
             ,[Authentication]
             ,[Error_User_System]
             ,[Error_User_Application]
         )
         SELECT 
            [Error_Number]              = ISNULL(@Error_Number,ERROR_NUMBER())  
            ,[eRROR_LINE]               = ISNULL(@Error_LINE,ERROR_LINE())  
            ,[Error_Location]           = ISNULL(@Error_Location,ERROR_MESSAGE())
             ,[Error_Message]            = ISNULL(@Error_Message,ERROR_MESSAGE())
             ,[SPID]                     = @@SPID -- SESSION_id/connection_number
             ,[Program_Name]             = ses.program_name
             ,[Client_Address]           = con.client_net_address
             ,[Authentication]           = con.auth_scheme           
            ,[Error_User_System]         = SUSER_SNAME()
             ,[Error_User_Application]   = @UserID

        FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions ses
         LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections con
             ON con.session_id = ses.session_id
         WHERE ses.session_id = @@SPID

    END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
                  INSERT INTO ErrorLog
         (
             ERROR_NUMBER
             ,ERROR_LOCATION
             ,ERROR_MESSAGE
         )
         VALUES 
        (
             -100
             ,OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
             ,'Error Log Procedure Errored out'
         )
     END CATCH

END
 GO
```

And the trigger code for a table called `test_error_handler` having 2 columns , ID and name .

```
Create trigger tr_test_error_handler
 on test_error_handler
 for insert as
begin

BEGIN TRY
         if exists(select * from inserted where name='rim')
         raiserror('test error', 16,1) 
         rollback 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        EXEC [ErrorLog_proc]
END CATCH

end
```

Note that if I run the following code just by itself the `errorlog` table gets populated but this doesn't happen when the code is in trigger body !!!!

```
BEGIN TRY
         if exists(select * from test_error_handler where name='rim')
         raiserror(50002, 16,1) 
         rollback 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        EXEC [ErrorLog_Ins_Error_Dtl]
END CATCH
```

Comment: Remove the **rollback** from trigger. that might cause the problem...

Comment: You can't end a transaction inside a trigger. Maybe you should look at `instead of` triggers. (e.g. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/898089/how-to-work-with-instead-of-trigger-in-sql-server-2012/)

Comment: I have removed the `rollback` but still the same error . Also tried to make it an instead of trigger but no luck

Comment: The problem is explained well here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980318/trigger-error-the-current-transaction-cannot-be-committed-and-cannot-support-op