# Stop SQL Server/EF from doing an automatic rollback

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

So, I'm using EF6 to do some raw SQL queries, and I want to it in a transaction as I'm moving files based on the result from the queries. Here is a short version of the code:

```
using (var dbTransaction = customDb.Database.BeginTransaction()) {
    //Drop previously created tmp tables...
    customDb.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.bbldkmember_tmp', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.bbldkmember_tmp");
    //Create a tmp table to keep all the bulk inserted records
    customDb.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE TABLE bbldkmember_tmp ( " + TableCreateGuts + " )");

    //Insert all record from the files into the TMP table, move the files to the archive when done, error if the file fails. 
    foreach (var fileName in filenamesToHandle) {
        try {
            customDb.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                @"BULK INSERT bbldkmember_tmp FROM 
                    '" + fileName + @"'
                    WITH (
                        FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
                        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
                        CODEPAGE = 'ACP',
                        FIRSTROW = 2
                        );");
            //Move file
            File.Move(fileName, fileName.Insert(fileName.LastIndexOf(@"\"), @"\Archive"));
        } catch (Exception err){
            //return "Failed in file " + fileName;
            //ignore but log error 
            retval += "Failed to load file " + fileName + " with error " + err.Message + "<br />";
            File.Move(fileName, fileName.Insert(fileName.LastIndexOf(@"\"), @"\Error"));
        }
    }
    //Start doing stuff with the records that we succeeded reading.
    //Add a column that we can format a GUID into  
    customDb.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"ALTER TABLE bbldkmember_tmp ADD col47 VARCHAR(255)");
    //commit or rollback based on the results of a lot of checks
}
```

The problem is that after the loop, EF has done a rollback on the transaction. The ALTER TABLE fails since the column is already in the table IF one of the bulk insert fails.

What I WANT to do is read all files, ignoring files with an error in them, then process the contents and do a rollback if something here fails. Is this possible?

EDIT: here is a screenshot from SQL server profiler on what is going on, and there is obviously something I don't understand... 
[image: Strange transactions]

EDIT #3: So, I checked what happens when there is no error in the files. As you can see there is no second transaction started after the bulk insert. 
[image: All ok]

Further to try and make a workaround I've tried using a SQL server TRY CATCH, using SqlQuery<>. The result is identical:

```
//Insert all record from the files into the TMP table, move the files to the archive when done, error if the file fails. 
foreach (var fileName in filenamesToHandle)
{
    try
    {
        var c = customDb.Database.SqlQuery<int>(
            @"--Bulk insert: 
                SET NOCOUNT ON; 
                BEGIN TRY
                    BULK INSERT bbldkmember_tmp FROM 
                    '" + fileName + @"'
                    WITH (
                        FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
                        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
                        CODEPAGE = 'ACP',
                        FIRSTROW = 2
                    );
                    SELECT 1
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    SELECT 0 
                END CATCH                                 
        ").ToList();
        //Move file
        retval += "Loaded file " + fileName + " with message " + (c.First() == 1 ?"ok":"fail") + "<br />";
        if(File.Exists(fileName.Insert(fileName.LastIndexOf(@"\"), c.First() == 1 ? @"\Archive": @"\Error")))
            File.Delete(fileName.Insert(fileName.LastIndexOf(@"\"), c.First() == 1 ? @"\Archive" : @"\Error"));
        File.Move(fileName, fileName.Insert(fileName.LastIndexOf(@"\"), c.First() == 1 ? @"\Archive": @"\Error"));
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        //Critical error
        return "Failed to load file " + fileName + " with error " + err.Message + "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do a `dbTransaction.Commit();` before you leave the `using` block.

Comment: So what if you have a bunch of files to handle. All "work" but the last one throws an error. Do you roll back the whole transaction? Now you have files in Archive that are not in the db. Is that the intended behaviour?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing a commit() or a rollback() based on if my updates work. If anything AFTER the bulk insert fails, something is wrong with my code and I'm going to have to redo ALL the files anyway, so yes thats the intended behavior. Edited inn some more code to show how it fails.

Comment: We can't find errors in code not shown here. Post the commit code. Are you sure that EF aborts the tran? I doubt it. SQL Server sometimes does that as well in response to errors (yes, this is horrible legacy behavior).

Comment: dbTransaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        dbTransaction.Rollback();
                    }

Comment: So SQL server might abort the transaction because of a failed bulk insert?

Comment: Test whether SQL Server aborted the transaction. Execute in SSMS: `BEGIN TRAN; bulk insert...; SELECT @@TRANCOUNT`. The bulk insert should fail (make sure it does). Is there now a transaction open or not?

Comment: Yep, SQL server is to blame: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980318/trigger-error-the-current-transaction-cannot-be-committed-and-cannot-support-op

Comment: I don't see how that link relates to what you are doing. It is specific to XACT_ABORT. Anyway, could you determine that SQL Server aborted your tran? In that case I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, its a dual issue: First SQL server automatically aborts the transaction (se link) then EF detects that the transaction is gone and starts a new. Solution was to do the bulk inserts outside the main transaction. Please post and I'll mark as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server has aborted the transaction. EF was not involved. You can try to use `TRY...CATCH`. I'm not sure whether this will prevent the transaction abort. (You linked to a question that does not apply here because it is about `XACT_ABORT`).

A potential solution is to do the bulk inserts outside the main transaction.

Comment: Actually EF is involved in that it hides the correct error message because of the TRY CATCH. The "ALTER TABLE" statement should fail with error "The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file" but instead EF automatically starts a new transaction. The REASON i should get this error is explained in the post about the XACT_ABORT (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980318/trigger-error-the-current-transaction-cannot-be-committed-and-cannot-support-op)

Comment: Well, that's SQL Server "hiding" the message. It's gone when EF comes into play. At least that's what I strongly suspect.

Comment: If you try to run the same commands only in SQL server, wrapping the BULK INSERT in a SQL server TRY CATCH you will get the error "the current trans..."

Comment: True, but EF has no choice. The original error is not sent to EF by SQL Server.

Comment: Why is the original message not sent to EF by SQL server? EF for some reason starts a new transaction, so it must know _something_

Comment: I don't think EF starts a new transaction in response to the error. At least I have not noticed the evidence if it was posted here somewhere. I think it does not notice any error and issues a commit or rollback which fails because there is no tran. That causes the error. The insidious thing about SQL Server errors is that you rarely know for sure whether your tran was killed or not. It is such bad product design. Appalling.

Comment: If you look at the 1st screenshot you will see that the first thing EF does after bulk inserts is a "BEGIN TRANSACTION", then the alter table statement. The alter table statement fails because the part of the code that dropped and recreated the tables has been rolled back and thus I'm unable to add the column (because it already exists from the previous run).

Comment: OK, that indeed looks like EF starts a new transaction. That is weird. If true it would be a bug in EF.