# Spring Transaction - ROLLBACK in SQL

Tags: java, sql-server

I have to call an SQL Server stored procedure from Java/Spring, and there is a try/catch block in the SP with logging the error into a table. The logging is necessary there because the SP is also called manually or from database job, but causes error in my case because the call from Spring is transactional, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15984867/302151

Does a ROLLBACK in the catch block solve my problem, and if yes, is it a good practice? I mean

```
BEGIN CATCH
  IF XACT_STATE() != 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN
  INSERT INTO TBL_ERROR ...
END CATCH
```

If it does not work, what is the suggested solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should add support for active transaction (from spring call for exemple) in your SP.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @tranCount INT = @@TRANCOUNT
  BEGIN TRY
    IF @tranCount = 0
      BEGIN TRAN
    ELSE 
      SAVE TRAN myTran

    -- Do task here

    IF @tranCount = 0
      COMMIT
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @xstate INT = XACT_STATE()                              
    IF @xstate = 1
    BEGIN
        IF @trancount = 0       
        BEGIN
            -- The transaction was initiated here and it's valid, so rollback               
            ROLLBACK
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            -- The transaction wasn't initialised here.
            -- So just rollback to the save point 
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION myTran
        END
    END
    ELSE IF @xstate = -1     
    BEGIN
        -- Invalid transaction. There is only one think to do...
        ROLLBACK
    END

    -- Now you can log here (no transaction running so autocommit)

    -- 
    IF @tranCount = 0
    BEGIN
      -- One of both
      ;THROW     -- SQL 2013 and above to rethrow the error (if needed)
      RAISERROR ...  -- SQL 2008R2 and before
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
      -- Here if Spring need a transaction, you can initialise one just beforre rethrow error
      BEGIN TRAN
      -- one of both
      ;THROW     -- SQL 2013 and above to rethrow the error (if needed)
      RAISERROR  -- SQL 2008R2 and before
    END

  END CATCH
```

Are you sure is it not possible to excute SQL SP from Spring without automatically created transaction ? It will be simpler.