# Stored procedure causing transaction error while executing from C# application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure written in SQL database. It executes 2 procedures in different databases. The inner procedures are simple update and insert queries without any explicit TRANSACTION statement applied.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_1]
@UserID nvarchar(MAX),
@report nvarchar(max),
@sqlErrorMsg nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
EXEC    @ret = [db1].[dbo].[usp_2]
                    @user = @UserID,
                    @msg = @sqlErrorMsg OUTPUT,
                    @date = @reportDate

            set @sqlErrorMsg = 'Report update Status: ' + @sqlErrorMsg

            EXEC    @ret = [db2].[dbo].[usp_3]
                    @UserID = @UserID,
                    @msg = @sqlErrorMsg OUTPUT,
                    @date = @reportDate     
END
```

This procedure runs perfectly when I execute it in SQL Management studio. But when I run it using a C# code that calls this procedure, I get the following error:

> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support
>   operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction. The
>   current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations
>   that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

C# Code: (Conn is defined outside with proper connection string and is tested)

```
public int Upload_Excel_Timer(string userID, string report, out string message)
{
    int ret;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_1", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report", report);

    SqlParameter outputParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@sqlErrorMsg", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
    outputParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


    SqlParameter returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    try
    {
        if (conn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
            conn.Open();
        int tempval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ret = Convert.ToInt32(returnParameter.Value);
        message = outputParameter.Value.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ret = -1;
        message = e.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: @user1666620 Yes - it says so in the question: `This procedure runs perfectly when I execute it in SQL Management studio`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980318/trigger-error-the-current-transaction-cannot-be-committed-and-cannot-support-op

Comment: @Bridge sorry missed that

Comment: @allencharp: thanks for the pointer... But i do not have a try catch block  in any of the involved procedures... And it runs perfectly in SQL..

Comment: What do `usp2` and `usp3` do? Can we have the definitions?

Comment: Have you tried using profiler to see what command your application is sending?