# How to prevent an error in Try..Catch from blocking the transaction?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some TSQL code with the following pattern:

```
BEGIN TRAN;

DECLARE @Set int;
BEGIN TRY
    SET @Set = dbo.UDFThatCanTriggerAnError('ByCastingTheDescriptiveErrorToInt');
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @Set = -1;  --Default value;
END CATCH

--Really in another sproc called from here but shown here for brevity
SAVE TRAN Testing;

ROLLBACK TRAN Testing;

--Back to the original sproc
ROLLBACK TRAN;
```

(In reality the rollbacks are only triggered if there are further errors inside the sprocs, but hopefully that gives the idea.)

In testing on SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1, the transaction save operation consistently throws the error:
**The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.**

If I change the UDF call to one which doesn't raise the error, or replace the line with a different way of setting the variable, the code completes.

It'd be *so* much easier if TRY..CATCH blocks here could be made to work in the same way the analogous blocks do in .Net and let me elect to reset the error flag, rather than automatically assuming every last error is terminal - this one definitely isn't, and is much less code than any alternative way of controlling flow.

So - is there a way to reset the error status inside the Catch block or do I need to rewrite the logic to avoid the caught error being thrown in the first place?

Comment: If you have transactions that are started in one procedure and committed in another stored procedure like this sounds then there are some very serious architecture problems happening. You want procedures to be loosely coupled with other procedures. That means each procedure should be able to run on it's own.

Comment: I don't - question edited for clarity. Code written that way wouldn't run at all I think? All sprocs handle their own transactions and any appropriate nesting, specifically so they can run both independently and nested as required.

Comment: Well that is good. This question has been asked many times before. A google search for your exact error message has SO questions in most of the first page. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger Error: The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980318/trigger-error-the-current-transaction-cannot-be-committed-and-cannot-support-op)